# Angular 6 - @Input repeats output 4 times instead of one

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two components in an angular project.

Here is the code for both:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  msg() {
    console.log('my message');
  }

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-child [message]="msg()"></app-child>
```

**child.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**child.component.html**

```
{{ message }}
```

As you can see **msg()** will output a message on the console.

The problem is that the console message is repeated 4 times and not 1

How can I fix this so it just run's **msg()** once?

Comment: When you pass along msg(), you run that function and print it to the console, and then when you receive it, it happens again. Instead of passing the function (console.log), pass the message, and only use console.log in the child component. You don't want to put this into the child html tho, you just put it into ngOnInit, like so ngOnInit() { console.log(msg); } (where msg is actually a string, not a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why you are trying to pass a function inside of Input but I develop the following example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so2ss4),

Take a look in the **app-component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  message: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.msg();
  }
  msg(){
    this.message = "Show Message";
    console.log("Messsaje");
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<app-child [message]="message"></app-child>
```